# Unitaries moving around diagonal entries

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a matrix of the following form

W=$\begin{pmatrix}
A \ 0\ .....\ 0\\ 
\ 0\ B \ 0\ ...\ 0\\
0 \ ....... \ 0\\
..........\\
\ \ 0\ .......C
\end{pmatrix}$

where $A, B , ..... C$ are matrices not necessarily of the same size and $W$ is block diagonal. Can I always choose a unitary $u$ such that $uWu*$ puts the diagonal blocks of matrices in any permutation I want diagonally along the matrix W?

Comment: Here's a [wiki article on permutation matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation_matrix)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if all matrices $A \dots C$ are rectangular (though each can be of a different size). If $\sigma: \{1,\dots n\} \rightarrow \{1,\dots n\}$ is the permutation of columns/rows that you need to enact, the matrix of $u$ will have the form
$$ u^i_{\;j} = \left\{\begin{array}{ll} 1 & \text{for } i = \sigma(j) \\ 0 & \text{for } i \neq \sigma(j) \end{array}\right. $$

For example, if you have only two blocks $A\in M_{n\times n}$ and $B \in M_{m\times m}$ the matrix $u$ that switches them around has form
$$ u = \left[\begin{array}{cc} 0_{m\times n} & 1_{m\times m} \\ 1_{n\times n} & 0_{n\times m} \end{array}\right]$$

If Matrices $A \dots C$ are not rectangular, you need two different matrices to permute rows and columns, $W' = u_1 W u_2^*$.